# Where is my mistake causing my JQuery no to work with HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, mousedown, mouseup, onmousedown

I am  working on some code where my objective is to create ten divs on the page. The divs will all contain the same class name, no IDs, and be styled.  The goal is that on click that the div that is clicked change its style. I am using the 'This' function to achieve that however I cannot get my divs to change after I uploaded the file. On mousedown on any of the divs, only the particular div that is clicked is to change to 200x400 and red. The HTML text in the div is also supposed to change upon being clicked. Then on the mouseup anywhere on the body of the page all the divs should change back to green. Beneath is my code, I did have it working and now it seems I have messed up somewhere along the way. Any help would  be appreciated. I had previously posted but have since deleted that post since I had made some changes to the code. Since those changes I have had the problem of the styles not changing.

[My uploaded page](http://hcc-computerscience.com/lynch/page1.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
</head>


<style type="text/css">
    .div1 {
        background-color: green;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        color: red;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>



<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".div1").mousedown(function(evt) {
  $(this).css({
    "height": "200px",
    "width": "400px",
    "background-color": "red",
    "color": "green",
    "text-align": "right",
  }).html("Lynch");
});


$(".div1").mouseup(function(evt) {
  $(this).css({
    "height": "100px",
    "width": "200px",
    "background-color": "green",
    "color": "red",
    "text-align": "left",
  }).html("Chris");
});

    </script>


<body>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


<div class="div1">
    <h3>
        Chris
    </h3>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: FYI, `<style>` tags should be **within** the `<head>` section and `<script>` should be **within** `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: Jeeze!! Thanks Phil brainfart on my end with that one. I suffer with my tracking and sometimes go to wrong line. That change was made! By the way my uploaded page is http://hcc-computerscience.com/lynch/page1.html . No actions work

Comment: Your [`jquery-3.4.1.min.js`](http://hcc-computerscience.com/lynch/jquery-3.4.1.min.js) script URL results in a 404 and your `<script>` tags are still in the wrong location. Also, please read the marked duplicate to make sure your scripts run after your HTML is loaded and learn to use your browser's developer console to check for errors

Comment: Well thats not the link to my websitet because if you click the link I provided it takes you to the page. i thought you said <script> can be within the head or body, if it was in the body how is it in wrong place? I also did move it on the link to the <head>

Comment: When I wrote that comment, your `<script>` tags were still between `</head>` and `<body>`. Looking at your [directory index](http://hcc-computerscience.com/lynch/), you don't appear to have the `jquery-3.4.1.min.js` script anywhere. You need to download it or link to a [CDN version](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: jquery-3.4.1.min.js is in there. it is the src = jquery...

Comment: Did  i not do $document ready and thats why it will not initialize